# How would I conduct the following mixed-model analysis?

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to conduct the following analysis on human subjects data using SPSS. It is my understanding that it requires mixed modeling, and I would appreciate an explanation of how to do this. (It's rather urgent, so I would appreciate help specific to this situation rather than a link to a longer resource, although I understand if this is not possible).

The analyses involve two independent variables with two conditions each (call them IV1 and IV2), and two dependent variables (call them DV1 and DV2). Both DV1 and DV2 are dichotomous, but are mainly analyzed through averages across blocks of data, and hence could be treated as continuous. All data is within-subjects.

My main hypothesis is that when looking only at data from Condition 1 of IV1, there is no statistically significant relationship between [the extent to which IV2 impacts DV1] and [DV2], whereas in Condition 2 of IV1, as [the extent to which IV2 impacts DV1] increases, [DV2] decreases, and vice versa. I would like to determine if this is true. Moreover, it would be extremely helpful if there was some numerical measure of significance to quantify the impact of [IV1] on [the interaction between [the extent to which IV2 impacts DV1] and [DV2]], as opposed to simply running two separate analyses for the different conditions of IV1 and finding one significant and the other not.

The second analysis involves determining the extent to which IV2 mediates the relationship between IV1 and DV2. I was hoping to use a two-way repeated measures ANOVA, but it seems that would require DV2 to be continuous.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am passably familiar with how to conduct ANOVAs and GLMs in SPSS, but not much further than that.